# I want to distribute a Java application

Tags: java

I want to distribute a Java desktop application for Windows.
Which is the best method?

Convert a .jar fiel to an EXE file and bundle it with [NSIS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nullsoft_Scriptable_Install_System).

Or is there any another method?

I want it for a Windows application with an easy interface to install.

The application is 3 MB, but if I bundle [JRE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Virtual_Machine#Overview) with it its size increases. Is there any alternative, like adding some DLL file, etc.?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend [JSmooth](http://jsmooth.sourceforge.net/) as a really good open source program to create an exe from a jar. It also has the functionality to check for a JRE when executed which is important when distributing your application.

Comment: It is worth noting that the executable produced with JSmooth will still require a JVM to run it.

Answer (score 2):

Consider [Java Web Start](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Web_Start).

Answer (score 0):

**[IzPack](http://izpack.org/) And is cross platform**